# Startup Script to Uninstall Google Chrome Not Working

Tags: group-policy, google-chrome, uninstall, startup-scripts

I'm working with our sysadmin to uninstall Google Chrome on our network, which we manage via GPO. As it has been installed by the users themselves, by a GPO (which is now deleted) and manually by the IT Department, we thought that the best option is configuring a Startup script to run on all computers.

Before testing this on our machines, I wanted to see if it works on my own computer. We're planning to use [this script](https://sourceforge.net/projects/chrome-universal-uninstaller/files/Source/ChromeUniUninstaller.ps1/download).
I used [this guide](http://woshub.com/running-powershell-startup-scripts-using-gpo/) to help set it up.

I'm attaching a few pictures to help explain my setup.

[PoSh Script Overview in GPO Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kSbyF.png)

[Script Overview in GPO Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BeaZm.png) According to the guide, this helps me to run the PoSh script in bypass mode, without requiring me to sign my script/change settings to allow unsigned scripts to run.

I've set the "Configure Logon Script Delay" policy to 1 minute as per the guide, although I'm not sure if it is relevant to startup scripts.

When I shut down my computer/reboot it, Google Chrome is still there. I'm a bit suspicious of the script since it was last updated in 2016, so maybe it's worth taking a closer look at it.

I have close to zero experience with this myself (of course I tried to troubleshoot before asking here), so I apologize if this is due to a stupid mistake.

Answer (score 0):

The attached script is set to look into program files folder for the Google Chrome application.

For example line:
Reg64Key = Get-ItemProperty -path 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\Google Chrome' -name "Version" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

You say the users have installed themselves... I am guessing these users do not have admin rights? If so its likely that the users Google chrome will be installed into their user profile app data folder as they will have write permissions here.... EIther %APPDATA% (C:\users\username\appdata\roaming) or %LOCALAPPDATA% (C:\users\username\appdata\local)

I suggest you avoid using this tool from the web as its not really a good tool to find all variants of chrome. Seems to be more targeted at non domain use for Local Machine admins (ie home users)

I would start off by finding the location in which the Google Chrome executable is stored for the users and we can move from there.

If its in different locations on different machines, that will make the job harder but still manageable as its only likely to be in a handful of locations.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! So, if I understand correctly, it makes sense to modify the script to also search in other locations. I'll take a look at where Google Chrome is stored on multiple machines in our network and will update the question accordingly. But there's no reason for the script not to work on my computer, right? I installed Google Chrome with admin rights, so it is stored in the Program Files folder. It must be something to do with the GPO then.